# Sqlite3 - pandas module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I want to turn my database into `sqlite3` for pandas df

I'm using this piece of code:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('\path\db.db')
df = pd.read_sql('select * from db', con)
```

Trackback what I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    df = pd.read_sql('select * from db', con)
  File "PATH\pandas\io\sql.py", line 403, in read_sql
    pandas_sql = pandasSQL_builder(con)
  File "PATH\pandas\io\sql.py", line 578, in pandasSQL_builder
    if _is_sqlalchemy_connectable(con):
  File "PATH\pandas\io\sql.py", line 43, in _is_sqlalchemy_connectable
    import sqlalchemy
  File "PATHPython38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.sql import (
  File "PATHPython38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import (
  File "PATHPython38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py", line 32, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import util, exc
  File "PATHPython38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .compat import callable, cmp, reduce, defaultdict, py25_dict, \
  File "PATHPython38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 202, in <module>
    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Is there something wrong with this code? What is the reason for this error?

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson ```pip show SQLAlchemy
Name: SQLAlchemy
Version: 0.7.10```

Comment: @Parfait I've been releasing the same code on a different machine and it's running smoothly. Thats all what i imported `import pandas as pd` `import sqlite3`

Comment: Wow. SQLAlchemy 0.7.10 was released 6.5 years ago. Any chance you might be able to upgrade?

Comment: @GordThompson `pip install SQLAlchemy==1.3.18` it worked. I forgot that I once needed an older version and that's why I forced it - I just don't know why this error came here. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLALchemy 0.7.10 is *really really* old. Like 6.5 years old. It used `time.clock` which ...

> :1: DeprecationWarning: time.clock has been deprecated in Python 3.3 and will be removed from Python 3.8: use time.perf_counter or time.process_time instead